# Set ResponseType Stream in HttpClient Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, stream, angular7

We have a docker api that return stream data, and we want to read from and send data to it. We do it in node.js, but in browser its not possible, because we can't set stream response type in request.
How to set "responseType" to "stream" and simulate this code in node.js to angular httpClient?

```
function exec(ctx: Command, id: string, host: string, data: {}) {
   return axios.post(host + `/exec/${id}/start`,
   data, {responseType: 'stream'});
}
```

To something like this:

```
constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
}
getAppExec(host: string, id: string, data: ICreateInstanceCLIData) {
   return this.http.post(host + '/containers/' + id + '/exec', 
        data, { responseType: 'stream' });
};
```

Is it possible to simulate websocket by api endpoint and receive stream data from and send to it?